# Why does this Scala code not compile?

Tags: scala

I do not understand why this does not compile. It's complaining that friend which is of Mammal type does not have a talk method. But there is...

```
class Animal {
  def talk:String = "i am animal"
}
class Mammal extends Animal {
  override def talk:String = "i am mammal"
}
class Cow extends Mammal {
  override def talk:String = "moo"
}

trait Farm[+A] {
  def set[AA >: A](friend: AA): String
}
class CowFarm extends Farm[Cow] {
  override def set[Mammal >: Cow](friend: Mammal): String = friend.talk
}
```

Comment: Within `set` `Mammal` is a generic type parameter which is constrained to be a supertype of `Cow`. Such a type is not guaranteed to have a `talk` method (.e.g `Any`).

Comment: Why you need your farm to have covariance type?

Comment: So that one can do something like `val x:Farm[Animal] = new CowFarm`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `set` `Mammal` is not the same `Mammal` that you declared a few lines above. It's a local generic type parameter that shadowed your existing `Mammal`. So your method signature is actually not different to:

```
override def set[AA >: Cow](friend: AA): String = friend.talk
```

Since `AA` is a supertype of `Cow`, it is not guaranteed to have a `talk` method. For example, it can be substituted with `Any` or `AnyRef`.

Comment: Hmm, this means that the body of `set` is limited to very generic methods like toString isn't it

Comment: @user1677501, yes, it's essentially the same as using `Any` as the input type.